# Google Drive to Tableau

Tags: google-drive-api, google-bigquery, tableau-api

Is it possible to use Google BigQuery to channel Google Documents into Tableau? Is there another way to do this without downloading the documents from drive onto a local machine?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tableau 8.0, there is data connection item for Google BigQuery so i would say yes

Comment: Alright, on the Google side - how do you channel the drive documents through bigquery?

Comment: There is no way currently to directly load google drive documents into BigQuery. You'd need to move them into Google Cloud Storage first, or download them locally and then load into BigQuery from there.